# Calling template class member function through a pointer [why is this valid c++]?

Tags: c++, class, templates, pointers, syntax

I was looking through the source for a large Molecular Dynamics code and found something I don't understand. I've created a simple test case in a file named test.cpp (shown below):

```
template <class T> class Test {
  public:
    void testFunc() {
      T *ptr1;
      ptr1 = ptr1.function();
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine with GNU's g++ as well as Intel's icpc if you invoke the compiler as follows:

```
$CXX -o test.o -c test.cpp
```

I do not understand why this is valid c++ syntax.  To access `function()`, which was never defined in the first place, I should have to dereference `ptr1` or use the `->` operator.

Are the compilers reading this situation differently than I am?

If you want to see the original source where I found this, checkout lines 556 and 595 of this file:
https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/doxygen/MsmMap_8h-source.html

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever instantiate the template class and call `testFunc()` function somewhere? See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70111f6903828080) please.

Comment: I did and got the same place you did.  However the original source I took this from compiles just fine using this.  See the edit I made.

Comment: I don't see where the `.` operator is used there with `buf` or `gbuf` though.

Comment: Line 595 defines gdata as a pointer to type T.  Line 556 accesses the buffer() function without dereferencing gdata.

Comment: gdata is an *array* of type T, not a pointer. But it shouldn't work, no. Should be `g.buffer()` and `buffer()`.

Comment: There's another class in that that uses `Array<T> gdata`. I bet the one you found is *supposed* be the same. Are you sure that the version of the header file you compiled is identical to the doxygen-generated version you linked to?

Comment: @Shawn yes they're definitely the same.  That's an interesting point.  I was able to fix my problem by changing the source to match the other instances (Array<T> gdata).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it's not valid C++ syntax.
Remember, Test is not a class, it a *template* for a class. It's your instructions to the compiler on how to go about constructing a Test class for a specific type T *if you ask it to.*
You haven't asked it to.

Try adding something like

```
Test< int > *test = new Test< int >();
test->testFunc();
```

You should get an error like

```
error: request for member 'function' in 'ptr1', which is of non-class type 'int*'
```

Comment: Why the `new`??

Comment: Why does this work in the original application then?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - Because I declared a Test<int> pointer. If you prefer a stack variable, then
    Test< int > test;
    test.testFunc();

Comment: @MarkMackey, because the template is never used.

Comment: @binky That would do just fine without further confusion and complication. See what I've linked at my comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I'm not sure pointers are all that confusing, but yes, it's marginally simpler. But people don't follow links - put your code in your answer. :-)